# nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... while running command

Tags: node.js

anishkhatri@Anishs-MacBook-Pro TrainerRoomProject-main % npm run server

> mern-auth@1.0.0 server
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.16
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
(node:77344) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
node:events:505
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1372:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1508:7)
at Function.listen (/Users/anishkhatri/Downloads/TrainerRoomProject-main/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
at Object. (/Users/anishkhatri/Downloads/TrainerRoomProject-main/server.js:41:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1399:8)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -48,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 5000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: No question just copy&paste?! This question has already answered thousand times.

Comment: kill the port 5000 or run the process in another free port.

Answer (score 0):

First install kill-port package globally

```
npm i -g kill-port
```

After installing the package run this command to kill the port

```
npx kill-port 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Address that your're trying to use is already in use. Try:

```
lsof -i:5000 // or another port

// this command will give ids of processes running on a certain port

kill -9 [process]
```